# Why JXL not working inside loop

Tags: java, jxl

Here is my JXL and Jsoup code

```
public static final String EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION = "E:\\xll.xls";
public static WritableWorkbook myFirstWbook = null;

myFirstWbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION));

for(i=0; i <= j; i++){
    // create an Excel sheet
    WritableSheet excelSheet = myFirstWbook.createSheet("Sheet 1", 0);

    // add something into the Excel sheet
    Label label = new Label(1, i+1, "Test Count");

    try {
        excelSheet.addCell(label);
    } catch (WriteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    myFirstWbook.write();
}
```

addCell(label) not working in loop. Why? If you use this without loop and for one cell it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because everytime the sheet or workbook is instantiated, all of it's previous syntax ***disappears***. Which is the case of your loop.

Try this:

```
public static final String EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION = "E:\\xll.xls";
public static WritableWorkbook myFirstWbook = null;

myFirstWbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION));

// create an Excel sheet
WritableSheet excelSheet = myFirstWbook.createSheet("Sheet 1", 0);

for(i=0; i <= j; i++){

    // add something into the Excel sheet
    Label label = new Label(1, i+1, "Test Count");

    try {
        excelSheet.addCell(label);
    } catch (WriteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Crawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
myFirstWbook.write();
myFirstWbook.close();
```